# Parallelogram: find the difference between the lengths of the diagonals?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Two different sides of a *parallelogram* are $8 \ \mathrm{cm}$ and $6 \ \mathrm{cm}$ and the ratio of the diagonals is 3 : 4.
Find the difference between the lengths of the diagonals?

I clearly understood that if $x$ & $y$ are the diagonals, then $x=4k$ and $y=3k$ where $k$ is some constant.

We know that the $x + y = 2 (a + b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are sides.

But still I am not able to get the right answer.
There is no option in MCQ:

- 5
- 7
- 8
- $\sqrt8$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the cosine's law twice to obtain what follows:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2} = 6^{2} + 8^{2} - 2\times 6\times 8\cos(\theta)\\\\
y^{2} = 6^{2} + 8^{2} + 2\times 6\times 8\cos(\theta)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow x^{2} + y^{2} = 200
\end{align*}

Since $4x = 3y$, one gets the solution $(x,y) = (6\sqrt{2},8\sqrt{2})$ according to the calculations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + y^{2} = 200\\\\
4x = 3y
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
16x^{2} + 16y^{2} = 3200\\\\
4x = 3y
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
25y^{2} = 3200\\\\
4x = 3y
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
y^{2} = 128\\\\
4x = 3y
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the answer should be $y - x = 2\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{8}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Oh damn! so i got it wrong its not x + y = 2 (a + b)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the parallelogram ($ABCD$) OP's talking about:

[image: Parallelogram]

According to the question, AB = 8 cm and AD = 6 cm. Also given that $\frac{BD}{AC}=\frac{4}{3}$. Asking is what the difference between the lengths of the diagonals $(BD - AC)$.

This cab be easily solved by applying [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) twice on two triangles carring these two diogonals. Suppose $AC = x$, $BD = y$, and $\angle ADC = \alpha$. Thus, parallelogram's propaties gives us, $\angle BCF = \alpha$ and $\angle BCD = \pi -\alpha$.

Now let's apply Law of cosines on $\triangle ACD$ where $AC=x, AD = 6,$ and $CD = 8$:
$$x^2 = 6^2 + 8^2 - 2\times 6\times 8\cos (\alpha) \tag1$$

Now again, apply Law of cosines on $\triangle BCD$ where $BD=y, BC = 6,$ and $CD = 8$:
$$y^2 = 6^2 + 8^2 - 2\times 6\times 8\cos (\pi - \alpha) = 6^2 + 8^2 + 2\times 6\times 8\cos (\alpha) \tag2$$
Add the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ to give:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 2(6^2 + 8^2) = 200 \tag3$$

Since $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{4}{3}$ thus $4x = 3y$, you can get the solution by simplifying the equation $(3)$ easily:

$$\left(\frac{3}{4}y\right)^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{9}{16}\right)y^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{25}{16}\right)y^2 =200 $$

$$\therefore \ y = \sqrt{8 \times 16} = 4\sqrt{8}$$
Thus, $x = \frac{3}{4} y =\frac{3}{4} \times 4\sqrt{8} = 3\sqrt{8}$

Consequently,
$$y - x = 4\sqrt{8} - 3\sqrt{8} = \sqrt{8}$$

Comment: I really like the way how you taken some time to put the figure and explain. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + y^2 = 2 (A^2 + B^2)$$
Where,
$x$ & $y$ are the diagonals of a parallelogram;
$A$ & $B$ are the sides which is in our case 8 & 6

And we got the ratio as 3:4 nothing but $x=4k$ & $y=3k$

$$16k^2+9k^2=2(8^2+6^2)$$
from which $$k=\sqrt8$$
now that we need the difference
rest is simple calculation.
Answer is $$k=\sqrt8$$

Comment: thanks for the edit @mathew